# Django - Trying to return object.id to see item as id in list at the admin site but TypeError at /.../1/change/

Tags: python, django, django-models

I created a model and registered it for the admin site but when I enter the admin site it is shown like "intensivecare_forms_data object (1)" I just try to make it id number to see it in the list I wrote return code but when I try to click on it it gives error.

```
class intensivecare_forms_data(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    data = models.JSONField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.id
```

This is the error.

```
TypeError at /admin/DataCollector/intensivecare_forms_data/1/change/

__str__ returned non-string (type int)

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/admin/DataCollector/intensivecare_forms_data/1/change/
Django Version:     3.2.4
Exception Type:     TypeError
Exception Value:    

__str__ returned non-string (type int)

Exception Location:     /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py, line 1632, in _changeform_view
Python Executable:  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3
Python Version:     3.9.6
```

Comment: Your __str__ function should return a type string, but in your case, it's returning an integer. I think that the exception message is clear here. Also, please, use PEP8 for naming, e.g. this class should be IntensivecareFormsData (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For both `id` and `name`:

```
def __str__(self):
    return f'Id = {self.id}, name = {self.data.name}'
```

I have never used `JSONField`, so I am not sure about the `name` part. If the above code doesn't work. Try this and let me know if this worked.

```
def __str__(self):
        return f'Id = {self.id}, name = {self.data["name"]}'
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What should I do if I want both id and name?

Comment: I have made the edits. Let me know if it worked.